# ASP.Net: missing references

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'm new to ASP.Net. I have access to an existing solution. When I opened it in Studio, some of the projects seems to be missing certain references. For example, one of the projects seems to be missing `nunit.framework`. I looked at the `.csproj` file and saw this:

```
<Reference Include="nunit.framework, Version=2.4.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=96d09a1eb7f44a77, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>..\..\references\nunit.framework.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

I'm guessing that my machine doesn't have this DLL?

I tried right clicking the `References` folder, then `Add Reference` and looked for `nunit` under the `Assemblies`. Nothing found. Is my system just missing this? If so, how do I get it?

Other missing references: `System.Web.Extensions` and `Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data`.

Comment: I think you can add the NUnit dll's through NuGet: http://nuget.org/packages/NUnit/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NUnit is a unit-testing framework. You can download it [here](http://nunit.org/?p=download), at which point you'll have it. Or you could presumably remove it, and then remove whatever unit-testing code had been written in that project, if you just needed it to compile right now for yourself. (It's generally a good idea to isolate your unit testing code to its own project, so only that project has to reference your testing framework's dll(s), but that was presumably not done in that case - if it *was* solely a test project, you could just unload the project if you didn't need to run the tests.

Comment: I think you can also add the DLL's through NuGet: http://nuget.org/packages/NUnit/ Saves the hassle of having to add the references yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You should download and install these applications. You can also use Extension Manager in VS to install Web.Extensions and Nunit.